# Chrome Extension: Is there a means of running JavaScript to procure inner html on a page and saving it to a variable in the extension?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm looking to grab the inner html of the page I am on in order to paste it into another tab in specific form fields. What is the best if any way to go about using JavaScript or another means to grab this data and have it usable across tabs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `document.documentElement.innerHTML` to get inner html of the page, as for storage, take a look at [chrome.storage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage).

And be aware the maximum amount of data that can be stored in local is 5MB, consider add `unlimitedStorage` permission if needed.

```
chrome.storage.local.set({"Your Key": document.documentElement.innerHTML});
```